# Creating search by array in laravel using where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have created a controller that uses a sql query to search recipe that has three ingredient chicken, onion and garlic. The controller is:

```
public function searchingbying(request $request){

         $dataSet = [];
        foreach ($request['ing'] as $ing) {
            $dataSet[] = [
                $ing,   
            ];
        }

    $result= DB::select(DB::raw('select recipe_list.recipe_id, recipe_list.Recipe_name, count(*) as ing_count,  count(ing_list.ing_id) as ing_match_count  from recipe_inglist ri inner join  (select Ing_id from ing_list where Ing_list.Ing_name="Chicken" or ing_list.Ing_name="onion" or ing_list.Ing_name="Garlic" )  ing_list on ri.ing_id = ing_list.ing_id right outer join recipe_list on recipe_list.recipe_id = ri.Recipe_id  group by recipe_list.recipe_id, recipe_list.Recipe_name having ing_match_count = ing_count'));
      }
```

the above query gives the output:

[image: resultstable]

The problem is that i want to allow users to select as many ingredient as they want which they select from checkboxes and the values of those checkboxes can be received from the $request. But how can i make it so that the sql part:

```
 where Ing_list.Ing_name="Chicken" or ing_list.Ing_name="onion" or ing_list.Ing_name="Garlic"
```

keeps looping till all the ingredients received from the check box are inserted in the query. Like if the user select onion garlic tomato and cheese the "where" part of the query must be :

```
where Ing_list.Ing_name="onion" or ing_list.Ing_name="garlic" or ing_list.Ing_name="tomato" or ing_list.Ing_name="cheese"
```

When two items  onion and garlic are selected the dumped data of  $data gives:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "onion" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Garlic" } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL's `IN()`:

```
where Ing_list.Ing_name in('" . implode("','", $data) . "')
```

> Note: this kind of query building is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You may use **PDO** in Laravels database system, by using the second argument as an binding array ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries)). Moreover, you could use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) as it's a more convenient way to communicate with your database.

Comment: i am very new to this. i tried doing this :         $result= DB::select(DB::raw('select recipe_list.recipe_id, recipe_list.Recipe_name, count(*) as ing_count, count(ing_list.ing_id) as ing_match_count 
            from recipe_inglist ri inner join (select Ing_id from ing_list where Ing_list.Ing_name in('" . implode("','", $data) . "') ) 
            ing_list on ri.ing_id = ing_list.ing_id right outer join recipe_list on recipe_list.recipe_id = ri.Recipe_id 
            group by recipe_list.recipe_id, recipe_list.Recipe_name having ing_match_count = ing_count'));
but it throws an error

Comment: You should use double quotes when opening/closing the raw method.